# jQuery.validate's form.valid() is preventing button Loading animation from showing (blocks JavaScript UI thread)

Tags: jquery, button, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-validate, jquery-validation-engine

Right now I have a `Save` button on a big/large form with lots of input elements (~ 500 inputs). These inputs are loaded through AJAX and a big part of them are hidden inputs.

When clicking the `Save` button I call:

```
// Save button click
$("#save").click(function ()
{
    var button = $(this);

    button.button('loading');

    if($("form").valid())
    {
        ... AJAX Post here ...
    }
    else
    {
        button.button('reset');
    }
}
```

The problem is that the `Loading` animation provided by [Twitter Bootstrap button](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#buttons) won't fire because `$("form").valid()` is pretty intensive and blocks the UI thread. I tested it removing the call to `$("form").valid()` and the Loading animation just shows as expected.

I'd like to see the `Loading` animation while the form is being processed. The way it is now the animation just flashes when the code passes`$("form").valid()`... the user can barely see it.

Is there any easy approach I can follow to give the `Loading` button some time while the jQuery validate `valid()` function is doing its work?

Comment: can you not have the hide button on the ajax response? You have to hide it either on success or failure

Comment: @karthikr Yes... I have it here too: `complete: function () { button.button('reset'); }`, but this isn't the problem. I'd like to see the Loading animation while the form is being processed... this doesn't happen the way it is now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem in a different way...

Instead of validating the entire form with hundreds of input fields (a time consuming process), I validate ***only the modified fields***, that is, I call `$("form").validate().element(this)`, where `this` is the input element that had its valued modified by the user.

Using [`jQuery`](http://jquery.com/) we can have something like this:

```
// Save button click
$("#save").click(function ()
{
    var button = $(this);

    button.button('loading');

    // Selecting only Questions that had their answers modified...
    var answers = // Your logic here to select the modified input fields

    var valid = true;           

    answers.each(function ()
    {
        $(this).find("textarea:not(:disabled)").each(function ()
        {
            if (!$("form").validate().element(this))
            {
                $(this).focus();

                valid = false;

                return;
            }
        });
    });

    // If any of the answers is invalid return with validation messages...
    if (!valid)
    {
        // Resetting Bootstrap's button back to it's original state
        button.button('reset');

        return;
    }

    ... // Do the AJAX POST here
}
```